# ValueError: The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1 class

Tags: python, text-classification, valueerror

```
SVM = svm.SVC(C=1.0, kernel='linear', degree=3, gamma='auto')
SVM.fit(Train_X_Tfidf,Train_Y)

predictions_SVM = SVM.predict(Test_X_Tfidf)

print("SVM Accuracy Score -> ",accuracy_score(predictions_SVM, Test_Y)*100)
```

> And Error : ValueError                                Traceback (most
>   recent call last)  in ()
>         1 SVM = svm.SVC(C=1.0, kernel='linear', degree=3, gamma='auto')
>   ----> 2 SVM.fit(Train_X_Tfidf,Train_Y)
>         3 # predict the labels on validation dataset
>         4 predictions_SVM = SVM.predict(Test_X_Tfidf)
>         5 # Use accuracy_score function to get the accuracy
>
> 1 frames /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/_base.py
>   in _validate_targets(self, y)
>       529             raise ValueError(
>       530                 "The number of classes has to be greater than one; got %d"
>   --> 531                 " class" % len(cls))
>       532 
>       533         self.classes_ = cls
>
> ValueError: The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1
>   class

How to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

This means that you only have one class in your training data. This is what internally the code does in the `fit` method

```
self.classes_ = np.unique(y)
```

and it then validates it by checking if there are less than 2 classes.
You can confirm it by doing `np.unique(Train_Y)`